# Get the value of /page/2 rather than using /page?id=2

Tags: asp.net-core, path, razor-pages

I am using a razor page and want to get the value from the path. What is the correct way to do this using the razor page or do I have to parse the Http URL?

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public void OnGet(string id)
    {
        if(id == null)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the razor syntax `@page` in your `.cshtml` file like below:

```
@page "{id?}"
```

`[HttpGet("{id}")]` cannot be applied to Razor Pages, remove it in your `.cshtml.cs` file.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#custom-routes